# Dump GPU memory in CNTK Artistic Styling Transfer

Tags: python, gpu, cntk

I am going through the [Artistic Styling transfer tutorial in CNTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_205_Artistic_Style_Transfer.ipynb). I can go through for one image then have to restart the jupyter notebook to avoid running out of GPU memory to style an additional image.The error code is blow. I would like to just put the last 2 codes blocks in a for loop that reads in a folder of images and creates a new styled image for each image. I think I'll I have to do is dump the GPU memory. If that is correct, how do I do that?

```
RuntimeError: CUDA failure 2: out of memory ; GPU=0 ; hostname=JOHN ;     expr=cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceBufferPtr, sizeof(AllocatedElemType) * numElements)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before processing the second image could you try calling

`del content_activations 
del loss
import gc
gc.collect()`

These are objects that will need to be redefined anyway and this way you clean them up (therefore freeing the GPU memory) before the next `content_activations` and `loss` have been constructed.

Comment: I used this method and it did it for the first 2 images but it errored out on the third. I am not sure this is performing better because of deleting those variables or I am using my desktop with 12 Gb of vram vs 4gb. Either way it is not dumping the vram. I would like to be able to create around 500 inferences.

Comment: I can verify this on my GPU (12 Gb of vram as well), except that it happens after a dozen or so images. We will work on a fix.

Comment: This has been fixed in latest master. The next release (2.0 beta 12) scheduled for Feb 22 2017 will have these changes. I have been able to run 100 iterations without ever going beyond 1.5GB of vram. In my test case I have the del statements and a call to garbage collector as in the (updated) response. I am not sure if they are necessary though.

Answer (score -1):

can you use other frameworks besides CNTK? You can just train your own models on a style transfer as a service site like http://somatic.io

Comment: Irrelevant answer.